# How can I use two random numbers generated in a function as matrix coordinates?

Tags: c, random, return

I came up with this function to generate two random numbers, r and c, so that I can use them in as coordinates in matrix board[r][c]. Is this even possible?

```
int coordAleatoria()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    int r=rand()%9;
    int c=rand()%9;
    while(r==c)
    {
        c=rand()%9;
    }
    printf("%d %d", r, c);
    return r;
    return c;
}
```

This is for a chess-like game. The PC is supposed to generate random moves. This function does generate coordinates, I'm just not sure how to make my program treat them as coordinates.

I hope I can get r and c in board[r][c] to be the values generated in coordAleatoria().

Comment: Call `srand((unsigned int)time(0));` only once at the beginning of `main`. And `return r;` followed by `return c;` is nonsense. You might want to look into a thing o the C language called `struct`, you C text book will tell you more.

Comment: Or just call `rand()` once without `modulo`, then take the `modulo 10` of the full number (use as first index) divide the random number by `10`, and then take `modulo 10` again and use as the second index.

Comment: `rand()%9` yields 1 of 9 values (`0`, `1`, ..., `8`). That seems wrong for chess.

Comment: Why are you avoiding the `(n,n)` diagonal? What about the other diagonal?

Comment: using a struct or passing two pointers to coordAleatoria. `cordAleatoria(int *p1, int *p2) {..., *p2 = c; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return more than one time. So you can combine the coordinates using structure as Jabberwocky suggested in the comment. If you are still finding it difficult than here is the implementation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>//for rand()
#include<time.h>//for time()
struct Pair
{
    int row,col;
};
struct Pair coordAleatoria()
{
    int r=rand()%9;
    int c=rand()%9;
    while(r==c)
    {
        c=rand()%9;
    }
    printf("Inside function: row=%d and col=%d\n",r,c);
    //Create a pair
    struct Pair p;
    //Assign values
    p.row=r,p.col=c;
    //return it
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    //Get the returned value as a Pair
    struct Pair p=coordAleatoria();
    //Collect the row and column values
    int r=p.row;
    int c=p.col;
    //Now you can use them here
    printf("Outside function: row=%d and col=%d\n",r,c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `rand()%9` generates 9 different values.  With `while(r==c)`, looks like code is looking for 9*(9-1) or 72 different pairs.  For a speedier approach, call `rand()` once.
- Code could return a single `int` and later divine/mod by 9 to recover the row/column.
- `srand((unsigned int)time(0));` should not be repeated  called in `coordAleatoria()`.  Call it once, perhaps in `main()`.

---

```
int coordAleatoria(void) {
  int rc = rand()%72;
  int r = rc/9;
  int c = rc%9;
  if (r==c) r++;
  return (r*9) + c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `rand()` twice (after properly seeding the random number generator with a call to `srand()`), you can simply call `rand()` once and take the first two digits as your coordinates, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} pair_t;

void rand_coords (pair_t *coords)
{
    int n = rand();

    coords->x = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    coords->y = n % 10;
}

int main (void) {

    pair_t coords = { .x = 0 };

    srand (time (NULL));         /* seed random number generator */

    rand_coords (&coords);

    printf ("coords.x : %d\ncoords.y : %d\n", coords.x, coords.y);

    return 0;
}
```

(**or** take the modulo of whatever your actual coordinate range is)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/coords_rand
coords.x : 9
coords.y : 8

$ ./bin/coords_rand
coords.x : 1
coords.y : 1

$ ./bin/coords_rand
coords.x : 5
coords.y : 7

$ ./bin/coords_rand
coords.x : 8
coords.y : 0
```

Comment: Good comment, bad answer :) *I understand: too long for a comment*

Comment: It happens. There are just so many good digits in each `rand()` seems a pity to waste them `:)`